# Semicolon weird behaviour in Javascript (If I don't put semicolon code doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, console.log

This is just out of curiosity, but do any of you have an idea why this code won't work?

**CASE 1**: If I don't put semicolon after `console.log()`, the code doesn't work.

```
console.log('foo')
[3, 2, 1].forEach( v => console.log(v) )
```

Output of case1:

```
foo
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

**CASE 2**: If I don put semicolon after `console.log();`, the code works fine.

```
console.log('foo');
[3, 2, 1].forEach( v => console.log(v) )
```

Output of case2:

```
foo
3
2
1
```

Comment: think of your code as `console.log('foo')[3, 2, 1].forEach( v => console.log(v) )` .. since `fn(x)[1,2,3]` IS valid javascript, you can easily see the issue - my advice, ALWAYS use `;` where they should go - it makes you a more professional looking coder - and nobody is using 9600 baud dialup any more where every character saved is important

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX finally I understood.

Comment: I have one doubt also, why this [[11, 12][21,22]][3, 2, 1] is undefined? @JaromandaX

Comment: I think because [11,12][21,22] is undefined which is inside an array and by using [3, 2, 1] you are trying to access the element of the array using index. But as you have specified multiple comma separated indexes, JS takes the last one mentioned i.e., 1 in your case and there's no element at index 1. If you had  [[11, 12][21,22], 10][3, 2, 1] it would have printed 10.

Comment: I think you are correct @Lakshya